# Separate Cloudwatch @message

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to get one log result per @message instead of having an aggregated one. See image

The query I am running is this

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| parse @logStream /.*\/.*\/(?<step>.*?)\/.*/
| display @timestamp, step, @message
| parse @message /^.*Workflow\:\s(?<@workflow>\d*)/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

[image: image example]